# Single button click to bind three javascript functions

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have created cascading dropdownlist for district taluk and villages when i click search button it must zoomed to all the three layers.but i assigned the filter value for village so that it will zoom to village if i give the same code to district and taluk it wont work ...please can anyone help me on this..

Here is my code for village same code will apply to district and taluk.

**default.aspx**:

```html
<div id="dropdown">
    <h4 style="margin-top:-3px">Cascading Dropdown</h4>
    <span style ="font-family:Arial">Select District : </span> 
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDistrict" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDistrict_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text = "--Select district--" Value = ""></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <br /><br />
    <span style ="font-family:Arial">Select Taluk : </span> 
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTaluk" runat="server"  AutoPostBack = "true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTaluk_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text = "--Select Taluk--" Value = ""></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br /><br />
    <span style ="font-family:Arial">Select village : </span> 
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlVillage" runat="server"  AutoPostBack = "true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlVillage_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text = "--Select village--" Value = ""></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
         <br /><br />
    <button type="button" " role="button" value="Zoom" onclick="Zoomto();" ><span class="ui-button-text">Search</span></button> 
     <br /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblResults" runat="server" Text="" Font-Names = "Arial"></asp:Label>   

</div>
```

**default.aspx.cs**:

```asp
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                   ddlDistrict.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
                    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
                    String strQuery = "select districtco, districtna from district";
                    NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(strConnString);
                    NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        ddlDistrict.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        ddlDistrict.DataTextField = "districtna";
                        ddlDistrict.DataValueField = "districtco";
                        ddlDistrict.DataBind();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        con.Close();
                        con.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            protected void ddlDistrict_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ddlTaluk.Items.Clear();
                ddlTaluk.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select Taluk--", ""));
                ddlVillage.Items.Clear();
                ddlVillage.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select Village--", ""));

                ddlTaluk.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
                String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
                String strQuery = "select talukcode, talukname from taluk where districtco=@districtco";
                NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(strConnString);
                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@districtco", ddlDistrict.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    ddlTaluk.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    ddlTaluk.DataTextField = "talukname";
                    ddlTaluk.DataValueField = "talukcode";
                    ddlTaluk.DataBind();
                    if (ddlTaluk.Items.Count > 1)
                    {
                        ddlTaluk.Enabled = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ddlTaluk.Enabled = false;
                        ddlVillage.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                    con.Dispose();
                }
            }
            protected void ddlTaluk_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ddlVillage.Items.Clear();
                ddlVillage.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select Village--", ""));
                ddlVillage.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
                String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
                String strQuery = "select villagecod, villagenam from village where talukcode=@talukcode";
                NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(strConnString);
                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@talukcode", ddlTaluk.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    ddlVillage.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    ddlVillage.DataTextField = "villagenam";
                    ddlVillage.DataValueField = "villagecod";
                    ddlVillage.DataBind();
                    if (ddlVillage.Items.Count > 1)
                    {
                        ddlVillage.Enabled = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ddlVillage.Enabled = false;
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                    con.Dispose();
                }
            }

            protected void ddlVillage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                lblResults.Text = "You Selected " +
                                  ddlDistrict.SelectedItem.Text + " -----> " +
                                  ddlTaluk.SelectedItem.Text + " -----> " +
                                  ddlVillage.SelectedItem.Text;
            }
        }
    }
```

**app.js**:

```js
var owsURL = "http://192.168.1.137:8080/geoserver/school/ows";
var layerName = "school:village";

function Zoomto(filter, SearchResultsLayer)
    {

var e = document.getElementById("ddlVillage");
 var villagenam = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    //alert("kkk" + villagenam);
    //var e = $('#ddlVillage').val();
    //// alert(districtname);


    var filter = "villagecod='" + villagenam + "'";
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.1.137:8080/geoserver/school/ows",
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: "parseResponse",
        data: {
            typeName: "school:village",
            outputFormat: "text/javascript",
            service: "WFS",
            version: "1.0.0",
            request: "GetFeature",
            CQL_FILTER: filter

        },
        success: function (response) {

            var SearchResultsLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            });

            SearchResultsLayer.setSource(null);

            var searchresultssource = new ol.source.Vector({
                features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(response, {
                    featureProjection: "EPSG:3857"
                })
            });

            SearchResultsLayer.setSource(searchresultssource);
            map.getView().fit(SearchResultsLayer.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize());

        }
    });
}
```